# Change information on hover of Plotly point

Tags: r, plotly

I'm using Plotly in R to make a scatter plot but currently when I hover over the point in my shiny app, the values corresponding to the x,y values appear. ex (19, 27.73k). However, I would like to change it to display a column corresponding to that data as well. ex (USA, 19, 27.73k) Would this be possible? IDK if relevant but current marker code

```
mode="markers", 
               marker = list(
                 opacity = 0.5, 
                 size = 5
               )) %>%
```

Comment: This is an excerpt from [here](https://plotly.com/r/hover-text-and-formatting/) `library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    x = c(1:5), 
    y = rnorm(5, mean = 5),
    text = c("Text A", "Text B", "Text C", "Text D", "Text E"),
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    marker = list(color='green'),
    showlegend = F
  )

fig` In order to provide a solution for your data, it would help to have some sample data using dput or something else.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `hovertemplate`, possibly in tandem with `text`.  Without data it's hard to generate exactly what you need, but you should be able to figure it out at https://plotly.com/r/hover-text-and-formatting/